# Laravel 4.2 controllers in subfolders

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a controller for each type of request post/put/get.

So my question now is, what is the best way to put controllers in subfolders when using L 4.2 ?

/controllers/subfolders..

I've seen some people using namespacing and some people simply makes a subfolder and put their controllers in it then run composer dump autoload-

But is there any "best practice" way to do it in L 4.2?

Comment: Please check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955335/routing-controllers-in-sub-folders-codeigniter

Comment: That is a two year old post asking about code igniter. I want to know what the best way to do it in L4.2 is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it the namespace way. One advantage this gives is that we can have same named classes inside the folders. Currently in a Laravel 4.2 app that I'm building, I am using controllers/api subfolder, with the namespace of Api for all the classes in it. And one of the classes is UsersController. Which might also be used for the frontend website, so now you will have to say FrontendUsersController, or something weird and long. So to avoid this, better get in shape with namespaced controllers.

Also, Laravel 5 advocates namespacing for your project, so does PSR standard. So this is probably much better way in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for you response @Sameer Nyaupane
But how do I use namespaces in controllers? Do I have to write use "the folder" and call the controller by the whole path?
Sry never used it so I am new to this

Comment: Is it like this:
In /controllers/Subfolder I make my controller:
<?php
namespace Subfolder;
class MainController extends \BaseController {

Then call it in the route as:
Route::controller('/somePage', 'Subfolder\MainController');

Is that all or do I have to run composer dump autoload?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes I was writing a response but then you already replied yourself :D, and yes that is exactly how you do it. And when you use it form a route you should call it like `Route::get('myroute-path', 'Subfolder\MainController@mymethod');` Yes, once you make any changes to your directory structure, you need to do a `composer dumpautoload` inside your laravel project path.

Comment: sorry for asking again @Sameer Nyaupane , but I seen some diffrent ways to write the controller.

Should i write 
use BaseController;
somecontroller extends BaseController {}

or can I simply write:
somecontroller extends \BaseController {}
Without the "use BaseController;" part

Comment: I would suggest you to make a new base controller for each namespace. What I mean is, if you are using `controllers/subfolder` , then you can have a `SubfolderController` which extends Controller. And inside `SubfolderController` , use the Subfolder namespace. This way, all other classes that use this namespace, will automatically have access to `SubfolderController`, without using \ or use. So bascially our `BaseController` is `SubfolderController`. :)