# Codeigniter Manage URL With Routes

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I'm just starting a new saas project alone and I'm stuck in Codeigniter's URI configuration.

I'm using xampp, and so far I have a folder with my site in it with it's own database.
If a client register to my product a new subfolder will be generated also new database will be generated related to this client.
The main URL is as ex: (http://localhost/gms/admin) but how to manage urls from clients like this : (http://localhost/gms/client1/admin) .... etc and after client log with his new specific url it SHOULD load the related database.

I Took time to solve it. Please need it necessary.

Comment: Refer this  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13955395/5188344

Comment: It does not solve my problem. When i type (http://localhost/gms/admin) it loads back-end successfully but when i type (http://localhost/gms/client1/admin) it shows The page you requested was not found. @Rajan

Answer (score 1):

in routes.php

```
$route['gms/(:any)/admin'] = 'gms/admin';
```

in gms controller

```
public function admin(){
    $client = $this->uri->segment(2);
    echo $client;
}
```