# access controller inside the controller directory within another folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

This is my controller directery structure

```
controllers
-----user(folder)
----------User_reg.php //My Controller inside user folder.

-----index
-----Welcome.php
```

I can access `User_reg.php` like this:

```
http://localhost/coin_system/user/user_reg
```

Now I want to eliminate **user** from this URL so I added the route

```
$route['user_reg/(:any)'] = 'user/user_reg/$1';
```

But it show the error: **404 Page Not Found**

#### I want to access it like this

```
http://localhost/coin_system/user_reg
```

How can i access the controller inside the directory in controller?

I have tried to solve using [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955335/routing-controllers-in-sub-folders-codeigniter) but it did't help.
I am using Codeigniter latest version. 3.1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add route with `:any` it also find your calling method after controller. But for index(which is default) its not compulsory to all index method So you need to specify route for it also. So just need to add one more route

```
$route['user_reg'] = 'user/user_reg'; // add this to route file
$route['user_reg/(:any)'] = 'user/user_reg/$1';
```

Comment: Thanks Your solution is working sir but can you please cleat one doubt that if i use this way so i have to create new route evertime when i create a new function?

Comment: No `(:any) => $1` will relate to function whatever you created

Comment: just one last question sir can it reliable to user this way or i should continue using the old (regular) way

Answer (score 2):

You have missed function

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

```
$route['user_reg'] = 'user/user_reg/index';
$route['user_reg/(:any)'] = 'user/user_reg/index/$1';
```

Or You can have different function

```
$route['user_reg'] = 'user/user_reg/somefunction'
$route['user_reg/(:any)'] = 'user/user_reg/somefunction/$1';
```

Also try with index.php in url

```
http://localhost/coin_system/index.php/user_reg
```

Comment: so i have to write a new route everytime when i create a function in this controller

Comment: Sir can you please clear the doubt that is that i have to create a new route everytime when i create a new function in this controller