# Codeigniter routes controllers in folders doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes, uri

I have these codes in routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home'; 

$route['controller1/(:any)'] = 'folder1/index/$1'; // working

$route['folder2/'] = 'folder2/home/index/'; //doesn't working
$route['folder2/(:any)'] = 'folder2/home/index/$1'; //doesn't working

$route['(:any)'] = 'home/index/$1';
```

My default controller is **home**. 
Now **any characters** to my home page like this: 
=> (localhost/mywebsite/(any category name)
=> http://localhost/mywebsite/**cars** taking me to the **home** page controller => index function. 
If that **any characters** equals to **any controllers without folder**, website redirecting me to that controller. 
But general problem is this, if that **any character** equals to **any folder** site doesn't redirecting me to that folder or controller inside that folder. See above code comments my folder route doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [routing controllers in sub folders - codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955335/routing-controllers-in-sub-folders-codeigniter)

Comment: I tried these before not worked.