# Sub-Sub Folder Access in Codeigniter Controller

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have created this flow in codeigniter:
Controller:
      Employee
         Sales
         Account

Now if i am accessing Sales Controller Function in View then i am doing like:
base_url()/Employee/Sales/FunctionName
Then its throwing 404 error.

Can anyone tell me how can i manage Sub-Sub Folder Structure in Code Igniter

Comment: Your question is not clear @Surbhi Gupta, please provide more details.

Comment: I have created a controller inside:

<pre>
1. controller
   1.1 employee
         1.1.1 sales
         1.1.2 account
         1.1.3 project
         
</pre>

now if i want to access function of any sub-sub folder controller then how can i process, its showing 404

Comment: By default, CodeIgniter routing is `contoller_folder_name/controller_name/function_name`, so when you write `employee/sales/account` it will search for `account function` in `sales` controller inside `employee` folder, thus the `404` page. In my opinion, you should make all the folders subfolders of `controller`. But if you must, you'll have to extend default `router` behaviour, which is not a very good idea IMO. See here, for more info - https://degreesofzero.com/article/controllers-in-sub-sub-folders-in-codeigniter.html

Comment: also have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955335/routing-controllers-in-subfolders-using-codeigniter